# Display image on text hover

Tags: html, css, mustache

For reference, the website I'm working on is https://truecolor.blog

I'm trying to have featured images appear as the mouse hovers over the blog title, similar to [this website](https://geordiewood.com/) and also [this one](https://newcenter.cargo.site/#). The website I'm working on is built on [blot.im](https://blot.im/how) ([documentation here](https://blot.im/developers)). [This blot template](https://preview-of-picture-on-bjorn.blot.im/) uses images featured in the markdown entry for the index thumbnail--not sure if any information can be helpful there. Ideally, once the user hovers over the text, the featured image would be centered in the middle of the page with a .5s ease transition.

Here's the entries page which acts as the index and homepage:

```
<html>
  {{> head}}
  <body>
    {{> header}}
    <div class="container index">

      {{#entries}}
      <p>
        <span class="light margin left">{{date}}</span>
        <a href="{{{url}}}">{{title}}</a>
      </p>
      {{/entries}}

      <br /><Br />

      {{#pagination}}
      <p>

        {{#previous}}
        <span class="margin left">
          <a href="/page/{{previous}}">&larr; Newer posts</a>
        </span>
        {{/previous}}

        <span class="light" style="margin-right:30px">page {{current}} of {{total}}</span>

        {{#next}}
        <a href="/page/{{next}}">Older posts &rarr;</a>
        {{/next}}

      </p>
      {{/pagination}}
    </div>
    {{> footer}}
  </body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
{{{body_font.styles}}}

body {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  line-height: 1.7;
  font-family: linotype-sabon, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  color: {{text_color}};
  background: {{background_color}};
  padding: 3em 4em 5em;
  word-wrap: break-word; /* for long words & urls */
}

.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  min-width: 320px;
  margin: 4em 4em 2em 222px;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {font-size: inherit;}

h2, h3 {margin-top: 2em}

h1 {font-size: 28px;line-height: 1.4}

a {color: {{link_color}};text-decoration: none;}

a:hover {background: {{link_color}};color: white}

.logo {float: left;}

.nav {float: right;}
.nav a {margin: 0 0 0 2em}

.small, .light {color: {{text_color}}}

.small {font-size: 12px}

.underlay {
  background: #f9f8f7;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0.0;
  top: 0;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0; }

.underlay--show {
  opacity: 1.0; }

hr {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 1.5em auto;
  border: none;
  border-top: 1px solid {{text_color}};
  display: block;
}

.caption, blockquote {color: {{text_color}}}

blockquote {font-style: italic;margin:0;padding: 0 0 0 1em;border-left: 1px solid {{text_color}}}

table {
  word-break: normal;
  word-break: keep-all;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

tr {box-sizing: border-box;border-top: 1px solid {{text_color}};padding: 0}
th, td {box-sizing: border-box;border: 1px solid {{text_color}};padding: 5px 12px 6px}

/* Date spacing for entry */
h1 + .light {margin-top: -0.75em;margin-bottom: 1.5em}

input[type="text"],
input[type="submit"] {
  font:inherit;
  font-size:20px;padding: 3px 6px;
  margin: 1em 0;
  border: 1px solid {{text_color}};
}

input[type="text"] {
  background: none;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 300px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.075);
}

input[type="submit"] {
  padding: 3px 12px;
  color: {{link_color}};
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid {{link_color}};
  cursor: pointer;
}

{{> plugin}}

.clear {width: 100%;clear: both;}

.archive h2.margin,
.archive h3.margin {margin: 0}

.archive h2.margin.left {left: -45%;}

/* MESSY RESPONSIVE BUSINESS */

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .container {margin-left: 140px}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1060px) {
  .container {margin: 2em 16px 16px}
  .archive h2.margin.left {left: auto}

}

@media screen and (max-width: 1060px) {
  .archive .margin {display: block;width: 100%}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .index .margin {display: block;width: 100%}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

  body {padding: 0.4em;}

  .container {margin: 1em 0 2em;padding-top:0.5em;border-top:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);min-width: auto}

  input {font-size: 1em;}

  input[type="text"] {min-width: 200px;}

  .nav {float: none;display: block;margin: 0;width: 100%}
  .nav a {margin: 0 1em 0 0;color:{{text_color}};}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please don't post a ton of code; post just the minimum necessary to reproduce your problem.

This will get you started.

```
<style>
#title:hover:after {
    content: url(image.jpg);
    display: block;
}
</style>

<p id=title>Title</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a span class and do something like this with normal CSS

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Image Hover</title>
    <style>
      .container {
        display: inline-block;
      }
      .hover {
        display: none;
      }
      .hover-text:hover ~ .hover {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span class="container">
      <p class="hover-text">Hover text here</p>
      <img
        class="hover"
        src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2017/abdul-sattar-edhis-89th-birthday-5757526734798848-hp.jpg"
      />
    </span>
  </body>
</html>
```